# Get directly dictionary<int, object> first key without foreach in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following Dictionary content :

```
[0] {75, SimpleObject}
[1] {56, SimpleObject}
[2] {65, SimpleObject}
[3] {12, SimpleObject}
...
```

I want to get first key, means 75, without foreach.

Maybe the `key` word should reffers to [0] not 75.

Because based on that key, I want to use that `SimpleObject`, I wrote:

```
SimpleObject s = dictionary[0] as SimpleObject;
```

but the VS2010 throws an exception:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I know that `[0]` means key number 0 from dictionary, means if I could have

```
[0] {72,  SimpleObject} //here
[1] {56, SimpleObject}
[2] {65, SimpleObject}
[3] {12, SimpleObject}
...
```

then I should get the correspondent `SimpleObject`.

Sorry, is first time using Dictionary and I want to learn more.

Question: How to get the number `75` and his SimpleObject ?

Thank you.

PS: I know that in StackOverflow already exists similar topic but no of them help me to get that key.

Comment: You're aware that dictionaries are unordered and it's entirely nondeterministic which object you'll get?

Comment: I suggest you use yourDictionary.OrderBy(c => c.key).FirstOrDefault() if you require a certain order in your dictionary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

...

dictionary.First().Key // Returns 75
dictionary.First().Value // returns the related SimpleObject
```

Comment: No prob.  Keep in mind what other people are saying about the unordered nature of hashtables, though.

Comment: Using `First` with a dictionary is pretty useless, it doesn't give you a predictable result.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Sometimes you don't care which object you get, you just need one - and any will do.

Comment: Unless the OP has Keys that are numerical in nature as his example, as others have said there is no way to ensure what key IS the first key, a key is more what this translates to. now Grabbing the key by int 0 does ensure that he gets key 0 where Dictionary<int,object> ; sorted dictionary may not give the desired results either , unless there is an order to his keys, which his example does not show. In this answer it should be stated : dictionary.First().Key // MIGHT Return 75.

Answer (score 5):

Not that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an unordered collection hence it has no concept of first or last.  The order of the items presented is essentially random.  You can't depend on it being the same between instances of your application.

If you do want some order then you should use `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead.  The items presented there are done so in an ordered way and will give you consistent results between runs of your application

```
// Consistent output is produced below
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, SimpleObject>();
var pair = dictionary.First();
Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary` is a (key, value) pair structure without explicit ordering. Maybe what you are looking for would be useful with a `SortedDictionary`, but it has no meaning with a regular `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dictionary.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

75 is the key value not the index:

```
SimpleObject s = dictionary[75] as SimpleObject;
```

A `Dictionary<T,U>` is unordered so you should not rely on the order of the key value pairs it contains.

Comment: use a `SortedDictionary` then or any other ordered collection - relying on the order of elements in regular dictionary will bite you later.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not an ordered collection, it doesn't have any indexes.

Use the key to access the item:

```
SimpleObject s = dictionary[75];
```

Comment: The content could be changed so `[75]` is not a solution.

Comment: @MichaelSwan: If you don't want to access the item by key, then you can't do what you ask for. The dictionary isn't ordered, so there is no "first" item. Perhaps you should use something like an `SortedDictionary` or a `List<KeyValuePair<int, SimpleObject>>` instead.